# Login / Logout using session in php

Tags: php, session

I am working on login logout using php with session concept. Created 4 files

1. login.php
2. checklogin.php
3. securepage.php
4. logout.php

I'm able to login with defined username and password when i logged in session gets started login.php will navigate to securepage.php if i copy securepage.php file in some other browser it doesnot gets open it will redirect to login.php vch works great.

But if i open securepage.php in same browser in another tab it is redirecting to login.php instead it should show securepage.php can somebody help me out in achieving it Thanks!

**1.Login.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Login Form</h2>
        <form method="post" action="checklogin.php">
            USER ID: <input type="text" name="uid"/><br>
            PASSWORD: <input type="password" name="pw"/><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**2.checklogin.php**

```
<?php 
    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $pw = $_POST['pw'];

    if($uid == 'arun' and $pw == 'arun123')
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['sid'] = session_id();
        header('location:securepage.php');
    }
?>
```

**3. securepage.php**

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['sid'] == session_id())
    {
        echo "welcome to you<br>";
        echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
    }
    else
    {
        header('location:login.php');
    }
?>
```

**4.logout.php**

```
<?php 
    echo "Logged out successfully";

    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    setcookie(session_id(),time()-1);
?>
```

Comment: Youre code works, tested with IE and Chrome browser.

Comment: Thank You @maxhb but still face same problem when i run dis program in my local machine i tried in chrome and mozilla Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**In checklogin.php**

```
<?php 
    session_start();
   $uid = $_POST['uid']; 
   $pw = $_POST['pw'];
   if($uid == 'arun' and $pw == 'arun123')
   {      
      $_SESSION['sid'] = '$uid'; # need to set user id instead of session_id()
      if (isset($_SESSION['sid'])) {
        header('Location: securepage.php');
      }
      else
      {
        echo "Error";
      }
   }
?>
```

**In securepage.php**

```
<?php 
   session_start();
   if(isset($_SESSION['sid']))
   {
    echo "welcome to you<br>";
      echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
   }
   else
   {
    header('Location: login.php');
   }
?>
```

**In logout.php**

```
<?php 

    session_start();
    if(!session_destroy())
    {
        echo "Failed to log out";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Logged out successfully";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you @Abdulla I replaced your code but still i do face the same problem i dont know why.
login.php ----> logged in it'll redirect to securepage.php
when i copy login.php and pasted in another tab in same browser it opens login.php instead of securepage.php Thanks!

Comment: @Sjay make sure your session_start() is in first line. and try again

Comment: @Abdulla included session_start() in first line in all pages still im facing the same problem is thr a problem with browser Thanks!